# Issues in the ERC20 token Contract burn

Tags: solidity, remix, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

[image: _burn function in ERC20 contract]

I was just going through this contract and that the _balances[account] is being deducted before the require statement. Is this still correct?
also there was no else and seemed like it will be transacted twice. This is the openzeppelin's contract and I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: Welcome! We ask people to paste code in instead of using screenshots. Here, you could link to the line(s) in the OZ being discussed, in addition to pasting it in (using three backtics (```) to create a code block).